# Finding a third degree equation that fits two points with given slopes in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I need to draw a line in my website, actually a curve representing a third degree polynom.
What is the easiest way of finding a third degree equation that fits two points with given slopes in javascript?

Find the third degree equation for(or find the coeffecient a,b,c,d in general formula ax^3+bx^2+cx+d = y):

startX, startY, startSlope

endX, endY, endSlope

Comment: A line would be a first degree polynom y = ax+b, and have slope=a everywhere. A third degree polynom is a curve.

Comment: Isn't this overconstrained? You have 6 constraints (3 points plus 3 slopes) but only 4 unknowns. You may want a fifth degree polynomial instead.

Comment: It is now. It used to be just start and end, in which case the third degree equation was a precise fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this is just straightforward math.

You've got an unknown expression y=ax<sup>3</sup>+bx<sup>2</sup>+cx+d. You can drop quite a few terms by defining x' = (x-startX)/endX (i.e. startX' = 0, endX' = 1). You'll also have to scale the slopes; startSlope' = startSlope * 1/(endX-startX).

From this it follows that d' = startY. That's your first free parameter.

Next, note that the slope is trivially obtained by differentiation. dy/dx' = 3a'x'<sup>2</sup>+2b'x'+c'. Therefore, c' is just startSlope'.

a' and b' take a pair of equations: endY = a'+b'+c'+d', and endSlope = 3a'+2b'+c'+d'. Therefore a' = endSlope' - 2*endY, and b' = 3*endY - endSlope'.

Comment: Well, since startX' is 0 by definition, you have startY=a'*0³ + b'*0² + c'*0 + d' .

Comment: You could also apply a substitutions from y to y', but that doesn't help in this case. You'd eliminate d' (as startY` would be 0, by definition) and you'd get back two constants in the y-y' transformation. (You can perform X and Y substitutions independently)

Comment: No. For instance, when you have startX = 5 and endX=8, and you need y(6), then you calculate x' = 1/3, and therefore y(6)=a'*1/3³ + b'*1/3² + c'*1/3 + d'

Comment: Ok back in first step. you insert in the formula y(x') = ax'^3+bx'^2+cx'+d <=> y(x') = d <=> y(0) = d. How do you get startY=a'*0³ + b'*0² + c'*0 + d' ? That has been baking my nuts

Comment: Please MSalter explain the above.

Comment: That's by definition: the transformation x->x' is defined such that startX' = 0 and endX' = 1. These values are chosen because they simplify the math; 0³=0²=0 and 1³=1²=1. There's no point in introducing a transformation y->y' because there are no inconvenient powers of y. Therefore, we use the y value startY in combination with startX' = 0 to get startY=a'*0³ + b'*0² + c'*0 + d', and similarly endY=a'*1³ + b'*1² + c'*1 + d'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 3-deg polynomial is ax3+bx2+cx+d, you have four unknowns.

Take the derivative to find the slope.  That gives three unknowns (the constant term drops out).

You have two deritive equations for the two slopes.  Please two equations for the (x,y) pair on the original equation.  Therefore you have a total of four equations for four unknowns.

Solve.